# Is 'were' acceptable in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is ***were*** acceptable in the sentence? That is, when a subject is singular and its complement is plural, does a verb always agree to a subject?

> Learning to cut up meat and use stone tools to process food ***were***
> crucial steps in our evolution.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use *were*. The plural *crucial steps* forces the subject to be interpreted as two things:
learning to cut up meat
and
[learning] to use stone tools

If the sentence were
Learning to cut up meat and and use stone tools to process food *was* a crucial step in our evolution.
then you could get by with *was*, but it depends on whether you are thinking of a single step, or two steps.

I think the plural version works better.